# Need a proof for an assumption on conditional probability density function based on probability theory

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, conditional-probability

While reading book "Elements of Information Theory", I came across an assumption used in a proof on page 33. The assumption is as follows.

Let $(X,Y)\sim p(x,y)=p(x)p(y|x)$. "If $p(y|x)$ is fixed, then $p(y)$ is a linear function $p(x)$. "

I can't understand the exact meaning of this "obvious" assumption. And could anyone familiar with Probability Theory could have a correct, concise and detailed proof on this assumption. Please show me in proof that 1) what does exactly fixed conditional density function mean, personally, I understand "fixed" does not mean a fixed constant but a fixed mapping from one set/space to another, but how to express it concisely? 2) what does "a marginal probability density function is a linear function of another marginal probability density function". Similarly, I think "linear" here does not easily mean $p(y)=c\cdot p(x)$, but how to express this linearity based on concept in probability theory?

p.s. One of my friends understood this assumption by Bayesian rule,

$p(y)=\frac{p(y|x)p(x)}{p(x|y)}$.

He thinks, if $p(y|x)$ is fixed then $p(x|y)$ is fixed as well as $\frac{p(y|x)}{p(x|y)}$. Thus, $p(y)$ is a linear function $p(x)$. However, I don't agree with him. And comments on this point?

Comment: In proving above proposition, I think three points are important to be made clear in proof: 1) what is mathematical definition/expression on "fixed"; 2) the linearity relationship between marginal density function p(x) and marginal density function p(y) 3) is the Bayesian rule proof correct? If not, where is the logic bug? These are my stupid ideas, any comments on those are welcomed. We can have a on-line discussion, even if we will make "many" mistakes. ^_^ truth does not fear contention!

Answer (score 2):

Some words might be missing and sloppy notations do not help but the *linearity* is the following.

Assume that the bivariate distribution $p$ of $(X,Y)$ is such that $p(x,y)=r(x)q(y\mid x)$ for every $(x,y)$ in the state space of $(X,Y)$, where $r$ is the distribution of $X$. (Then $q$ is the conditional distribution of $Y$ conditionally on $X$.)
Let $s$ denote the distribution of $Y$. Fix some $q$. Then:

> The mapping $r\mapsto s$ (distribution of $X$ maps to distribution of $Y$) is linear.

To wit, for every $y$, $s(y)=\sum\limits_xp(x,y)=\sum\limits_xr(x)q(y\mid x)$ hence, if $q$ is fixed, then $s=(s(y))_y$ depends linearly on $r=(r(x))_x$.

Comment: And I squarely disagree with your friend.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't think it is a correct proof. First, mathematical definition/expression on "fixed" is still unclear; Second, the linearity relationship between marginal density function p(x) and marginal density function p(y) is not explained well based on last two equations, e.g. what does subscript x and y mean? Third, is the Bayesian rule proof correct?

Comment: This assumption seems very fundamental in probability theory but I felt quite tricky in proof.

Comment: Let me suggest that you slow down on the use of the word "incorrect" to mask your misunderstandings and/or the lacks of your mathematical education. Two things are sure: the proof in my answer is "correct"; every desire to help you disappeared after your comments.

Comment: For sure, help is always appreciated and another thank you for your kindness and your interest in this little question. If not happy with my improper words using, I do apologize. However, in my point of view, giving a proof on a proposition (the assumption above) should be precise, concise and as easy as possible to understand. Maybe some other viewers interested in this assumptions, a not so good, or detailed proof will confuse them. Of course, if a proof is correct, we can understand and discuss it to make it clear on all aspects without any ambiguities left for others. Is that right? ^_^

Comment: So I kindly have above three unclear point in this question and the proof:

Comment: 1) mathematical definition/expression on "fixed" is still unclear; 2) the linearity relationship between marginal density function p(x) and marginal density function p(y) is not explained well based on last two equations, e.g. what does subscript x and y mean? 3) is the Bayesian rule proof correct? I think I am too stupid to answer these three questions, and any friends can give a help?

Comment: If Bayesian proof is wrong, and what is the logic bug in the proof?

Comment: Whom are you talking to? Me? What a strange idea...

Comment: If possible, could you please kindly teach me about your idea to proof this proposition? I do not understand the above three uncertain points, maybe because I am lack of Math education.

Comment: Hey can you guys please take a look at this question on conditional probabilities? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491813/expectation-of-conditional-distributions